# Change color of panel when mouse clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I am very new to visual C#

I want to make a ticket booking system (like in cinemas), I have created the seats using panel, each seating is `40 * 40`

Here's my code:

```
private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 12; b++)
        {

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), b * 40, a * 40, 40, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), b * 40, a * 40, 40, 40);

        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the color of each seating by a mouse click to show what seat has been selected; but so far no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off creating seperate controls for each of your selected seats and handling their Click events. In this example I added 24 `PictureBox's` to the `Panel`. I then placed their index in the `Tag` Property of the Control and attached a common Click Event Handler. I am also using a `Bool` array to keep track of selected status.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool[] selected = new bool[24];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (PictureBox  pb in panel1.Controls)
        {
            pb.Click += new EventHandler(pictureBox_Click);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        int index ;
        if (int.TryParse(pb.Tag.ToString(), out index))
        {
            if (selected[index])
            {
                selected[index] = false;
                pb.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                selected[index] = true;
                pb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use what you have if you create a boolean array to store the state of the Seat, use the Panel's MouseDown Event to set the variable and Invalidate the screeen rectangle that is accociated with your seat.

Something like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool[,] selected = new bool[2,12];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int a, b;

        for (a = 0; a <= 1; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b < 12; b++)
            {

                if (selected[a, b])
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), b * 40, a * 40, 40, 40);

                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White ), b * 40, a * 40, 40, 40);
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), b * 40, a * 40, 40, 40);

            }
        } 

    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int xPos, yPos;
        xPos = e.X / 40;
        yPos = e.Y / 40;

        if ((xPos > 11) || (yPos > 1)) return;

        if(selected[yPos,xPos])
            selected[yPos, xPos] = false;
        else
            selected[yPos, xPos] = true;

        ((Panel)sender).Invalidate(new Rectangle(xPos * 40,yPos *40,40,40)) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `Graphics` object and drawing directly to the form, you may be able to get away with simply setting the [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) property of the control that corresponds to the selected seat when the [OnMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick.aspx) event fires.

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do. Be sure to read up on event handling if you're new to C# and WinForms. Events are very important in Windows programming.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you give me an example of the code? Im very new at this and don't really know where to start

Comment: @TanyaLertwichaiworawit When I first started, the way I learned how event handlers worked was to simply drag a button control onto the form, and then double-click it.  This automatically generates an event handler for the button's *OnClick* event that will be executed every time the button is well, clicked!